# MediaRecorder saving data to buffer(setOutputFile)

Tags: android, mediarecorder

During recording audio using mediarecorder a output file has to be specified where the recorded data is stored. I would rather want to save the data to buffer and then create the file once the user saves the data.
So If i have something like this

```
 Recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 Recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 Recorder.setOutputFormat(outputfileformat);
 Recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
```

Instead of using filePath Can i directly save it to buffer??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have to go through the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class for that.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, AudioRecord only supports 8bit or 16bit wav and Android doesn't provide any codec libraries.

Comment: Nope.  It's a major weakness of the android sdk (and documentation - the supported media types page should list that the encoders are only supported for the MediaRecorder).
I'm trying to work around this but not to much avail.  
This article may be helpful: http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system.
Otherwise, you're left to integrating your own codecs most of which are C based (and most of which are royalty based).